# Create a Dynamic Number of New Columns in a Data Frame Based on the Levels in a Vector

Tags: r

I'm looking to add an unknown number of new columns to a data frame based on the number of unique values found in a column of another data frame.  I have the following two data frames:

| user | text.string |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | I like yellow submarines |
| Jane | I like red cars |

```
my.base.df <- data.frame(
  "user" = c("Bob", "Jane")
  , "text.string" = c("I like yellow submarines", "I like red cars")
)
```

| theme | term |
| --- | --- |
| colours | yellow |
| colours | red |
| colours | blue |
| cars | ford |
| cars | toyota |
| cars | fiat |

```
my.theme.df <- data.frame(
  "theme" = c(rep("cars", 3), rep("colours", 3))
  , "term" = c("ford", "toyota", "fiat", "red", "yellow", "blue")
)
```

And I want to flag the themes found in each text.string, to end up with something like this:

| user | text.string | cars | colours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | I like yellow submarines | 0 | 1 |
| Jane | I like red cars | 1 | 1 |

I think I can match the terms to the text.string with a for loop, but I'm worried it's not scalable outside of this toy example.  But the bit I'm really stuck on is that I can't create the "cars" or "colours" columns in `my.base.df` dynamically from the result of `levels(my.theme$themes)`

In the real world the number of levels in `my.theme.df$theme` could be up to twenty, with over one hundred `my.theme.df$term` matching a `my.theme.df$theme`.  Similarly, `my.base.df` could contain upto one thousand observations, so I'm worried about efficiency too.

Any help or pointers would be great?

Thank you,

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your data frame by theme, and then use the theme + all related terms on the relevant string.

```r
my.base.df <- data.frame(
  "user" = c("Bob", "Jane"),
  "text.string" = c("I like yellow submarines", "I like red cars")
)

my.theme.df <- data.frame(
  "theme" = c(rep("cars", 3), rep("colours", 3)),
  "term" = c("ford", "toyota", "fiat", "red", "yellow", "blue")
)

theme_split <- split(my.theme.df, my.theme.df$theme)

for (x in names(theme_split)) {
  # include theme itself in search
  terms <- paste(c(theme_split[[x]][["term"]], x), collapse = "|")
  my.base.df[[x]] <- grepl(terms, my.base.df$text.string)
}

my.base.df
#>   user              text.string  cars colours
#> 1  Bob I like yellow submarines FALSE    TRUE
#> 2 Jane          I like red cars  TRUE    TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your response caldwellst, but I'm not getting any matches on colours, both obs are marked as false

Comment: @JamieFay good catch, had forgot to change to using the names of the list! Should all work now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure it's changed

Comment: It's using the exact data frames you set in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably doing something wrong.  I've pasted in the code for the data frames in my original post, and the code from your answer, but still both obs have false in the colours column.  I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: I've added in the full code I put into `reprex::reprex()` just to be clear in case that helps!

Comment: Sorry, it's still returning false for colours.  Could be because "terms" contains "4|6|1|colours", is that correct?  Should the numbers and pipes be trimmed off?  Do I need to change some local setting maybe?  I'm using RStudio 1.4.1717 on Windows 10, if that helps.  Thanks again for all your help caldwellst

Comment: I took the c(...) function out of the paste(...) and now it works perfectly.  Thanks for all your help @caldwellst.  Apologies again for all the follow up questions